# Как правильно добавить библиотеку boost'а в cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, библиотеки, boost

Я хочу скомпилить код с использованием boost/thread

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;

void calc0() {
}
void calc1() {
}
int main () {
    thread t0 = thread(calc0);
    thread t1 = thread(calc1);
    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Для этого я написал cmake файл

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -pthread")
find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
```

Версию буста 1.71.0 скачал с репозитория ubuntu.
Данный код не компилится, пишет что библиотека не найдена, как правильно написать cmake файл, чтоб код компилился?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: `boost-dev` (или как его в дебианах зовут?) забыл установить?

Comment: @Fat-Zer да проще из сорсов собрать что надо, а не тащить всю помойку